# Unable to merge Dex error - how to search for duplicate dependencies?

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

I suspect the issue is some dependency conflict between `firebase-firestore` and `firebase-ui-auth`, perhaps some gms library. If I remove the `firebase-ui-auth` depency from my app, the error disappears, but if I add `com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0` it appears again.

My app `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            storeFile file('xxx')
            storePassword 'xxx'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.xenione.libs:swipe-maker:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
    compile' com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'


    compile 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0'
    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18'
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9'
    compile 'com.github.StephenVinouze:MaterialNumberPicker:1.0.4'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.fondesa:lyra:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My project build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository

        }
        maven{
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The project build fails. Error:

```
    FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService;

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 29s
```

How to troubleshoot this further and what could a proper build.gradle look like?

Comment: Scroll higher in the Gradle Console output than what you're showing, and look for a Java stack trace from the build process identifying specifically what failed.

Comment: I edited my post to include the full java stack trace, but I don't see any mention of any library there. Where else do I look?

Comment: `DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536` -- you have exceeded the 64K DEX method reference limit, which means that you need to double-check your work with setting up multidex.

Comment: If you set multiDex enabled to true then you also need to extend MultidexApplication

Comment: We're getting closer, but not quite there - I added multiDexEnabled. It worked for firebase libraries, but when I uncommented com.android.billingclient:billing, I got a new error: AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error converting bytecode to dex:\nCause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService;","sources":[{}],"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:\ncom.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService;\n","tool":"Dex"}

Comment: I understand the basic premise of the error, but how do I look for duplicate dependencies? I updated the question to follow the progress

Comment: Hi...Did you solved the issue...please provide the solution in answer